# jQuery Plugin Galleriffic working locally in chrome - but not online

Tags: jquery-plugins, galleriffic

under [Demo Gallery](http://c-m-d.info/demo/gallery.html) i've a small gallery running - using the jQuery Plugin Galleriffic.
I developed it in chrome locally. There everything works fine.
But when i upload it, in Chrome are no pictures shown. That's really strange, because safari, firefox, ... are showing it as wanted.
Can anyone give me a hint what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

ok now i found the error..
it was only adblock...! after disabling it, it works fine!
adblock thought my pics are ads, because they were in the folder "ads". Stupid error on my part.